# Can I play a hard copy of a game expansion with a game bought on Steam?

Tags: steam, fallout-4

I have Fallout 4 on Steam. I just saw a good deal in a physical store for the DVD expansion Far Harbor. Can I activate that on Steam or even play the expansion with my Steam copy?

Comment: I believe the physical copies require Steam to finish installing, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Comment: [People were getting VPN](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3s0ztf/step_by_step_vpn_tutorial_how_to_unlock_fallout_4/) to connect to Australia to get the game to unlock half a day earlier... Steam is definitely required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can. That's because the hard copy version of Fallout 4 is really just a Steam copy in disguise.

The Fallout 4 DVD box contains a Steam code, which you must redeem. You will also need to download the vast majority of the game from Steam, because the DVD simply doesn't have the data density required to hold Fallout 4<sup>*</sup>.

You don't even have to use the DVD at all. You can simply redeem the code and install the game from Steam without ever putting the DVD in your drive.

---

<sup>*</sup>: The Fallout 4 DVD contains 5.21 GB of data, which is less than 10% of the full game.

Comment: If I purchase the Far Harbor DVD do I also get a key top redeem?

Comment: The DVD copy of Fallout 4 and all DLCs are simply a Steam CD key inside a box.  You must have an online connection to do the initial install, and you must create a Steam account to play.  You have no choice in this.

Answer (score 1):

If a physical copy of a game is redeemable on Steam, there may be a little Steam logo and some info somewhere on the back, like shown here:
[image: Steam Logo]
Physical copy of *Rochard*, the Steam logo is near the center of the image. Apologies for bad image quality, taken with computer camera.

I noticed, when looking for a game to show above, that sometimes instead of a logo is just text. So, thoroughly check the back for DRM details.